# kernel initializers and epochs

Tags: neural-network, training

In a sample code like this (From Keras library):

```
model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
```

the kernel values will be initialized, say, randomly. My question is about epocs. If during `model.fit` I run 10 epochs, then during epoch 2, the kernel will be initialized randomly or the value will be taken from the backprop values calculated in previous epochs.

In other words, my question is, during every epoch the network behaves fresh for all given hyperparameters (and just backprop parameter are updated) or such hyperparameters' manual values are not considered except first epoch.

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: keras library this is

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but you could check the weight content at every epoch to see how random works:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))  
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print_weights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: print(model.layers[0].get_weights()))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, 
          y_train, 
          batch_size=batch_size, 
          nb_epoch=5 validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
          callbacks = [print_weights])
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039548/how-to-check-the-weights-after-every-epoc-in-keras-model